# Parsing XML from a specified Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Respected Techhie,
may some one please help me on this.

I have a xml data in a table in a xml column something like this

```
DECLARE @x xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ACES version="3.0"> 
<Header><Company>BIPRO</Company><SenderName>Karan Johar</SenderName><SenderPhone>988XX24153 ext 247</SenderPhone><TransferDate>2014-10-17</TransferDate><BrandAAIAID>BFNG</BrandAAIAID><DocumentTitle>Jhuolant </DocumentTitle><EffectiveDate>2014-10-17</EffectiveDate><SubmissionType>FULL</SubmissionType><MapperCompany>BINRO International</MapperCompany><MapperEmail>xsdfignol@korsaadusa.com</MapperEmail><VcdbVersionDate>2014-09-26</VcdbVersionDate><QdbVersionDate>2013-01-24</QdbVersionDate><PcdbVersionDate>2014-09-26</PcdbVersionDate></Header>
<App action="A" id="1" validate="yes"><BaseVehicle id="122862">2013, Mazda, 6</BaseVehicle><EngineBase id="2547">3.7L 6Cyl V (3726)(227)  3.76 95.5(Bore)3.41 86.7(Stroke)</EngineBase><Note>Relief Pressure:  15 lb</Note><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="2067">Engine Coolant Recovery Tank Cap</PartType><MfrLabel>Standard</MfrLabel><Part>T56</Part></App>
<App action="A" id="2" validate="yes"><BaseVehicle id="122833">2012, Ford, EcoSport</BaseVehicle><Note>Relief Pressure:  20 lb</Note><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="2067">Engine Coolant Recovery Tank Cap</PartType><MfrLabel>Standard</MfrLabel><Part>T58</Part></App>
<App action="A" id="37645" validate="yes"><BaseVehicle id="1">2002, Suzuki, Aerio</BaseVehicle><Note>Relief Pressure:  16 lb</Note><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="2068">Radiator Cap</PartType><MfrLabel>Safety Lever</MfrLabel><Part>ST37</Part></App>
<App action="A" id="37646" validate="yes"><BaseVehicle id="1">2002, Suzuki, Aerio</BaseVehicle><Note>Relief Pressure:  16 lb</Note><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="2068">Radiator Cap</PartType><MfrLabel>Standard</MfrLabel><Part>T37</Part></App>
<Footer><RecordCount>37646</RecordCount></Footer>
</ACES>';

CREATE TABLE tblFile (FileID INT
              ,ACES_Version VARCHAR(10)
              ,Header_Company VARCHAR(100)
              ,Header_SenderName VARCHAR(100)
              ,Footer_RecordCount INT
              ,HeaderNode XML
              ,FooterNode XML);

INSERT INTO tblFile
SELECT 1 AS FileID 
  ,@x.value('/ACES[1]/@version','varchar(max)') AS ACES_Version
  ,@x.value('(/ACES/Header/Company)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_Company
  ,@x.value('(/ACES/Header/SenderName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_SenderName
  ,@x.value('(/ACES/Footer/RecordCount)[1]','int') AS ACES_RecordCount
  ,@x.query('/ACES/Header') AS HeaderNode
  ,@x.query('/ACES/Footer') AS FooterNode
 from NETCHANGESource.dbo.tblFile
```

I am trying to have stored Procedure which parse the data and load it to `tblFile`.
 I tried like given above but getting error like

> Must declare the scalar variable "@x".

Can any one please suggest what is the error here.

i tried this code

```
create table HEADER
(
FileID varchar (10),
ACES_Version VARCHAR (50),
Header_Company VARCHAR (150),
Header_SenderName VARCHAR (150),
ACES_RecordCount VARCHAR (150),
HeaderNode VARCHAR (150),
FooterNode VARCHAR (150)
)

INSERT  HEADER

SELECT 1 AS FileID 
  ,t.c.value('/ACES[1]/@version','varchar(max)') AS ACES_Version
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/Company)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_Company
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/SenderName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_SenderName
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Footer/RecordCount)[1]','int') AS ACES_RecordCount
  ,t.c.query('/ACES/Header') AS HeaderNode
  ,t.c.query('/ACES/Footer') AS FooterNode
from NETCHANGESource.dbo.tblFile s
CROSS APPLY s.xmldata.nodes('/') AS t(c);   -- col is your XML column
```

but getting error
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 13
Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `nodes()` function:

```
INSERT INTO #tblFile
SELECT 1 AS FileID 
  ,t.c.value('/ACES[1]/@version','varchar(max)') AS ACES_Version
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/Company)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_Company
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/SenderName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_SenderName
  ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Footer/RecordCount)[1]','int') AS ACES_RecordCount
  ,t.c.query('/ACES/Header') AS HeaderNode
  ,t.c.query('/ACES/Footer') AS FooterNode
from @x.nodes('/') AS t(c)

SELECT *
FROM #tblFile;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417106)**</kbd>

If data is in another table you could use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
INSERT INTO tblFile   -- define column list here (FileID, ACES_Version,...)
SELECT 1 AS FileID 
      ,t.c.value('/ACES[1]/@version','varchar(max)') AS ACES_Version
      ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/Company)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_Company
      ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Header/SenderName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Header_SenderName
      ,t.c.value('(/ACES/Footer/RecordCount)[1]','int') AS ACES_RecordCount
      ,t.c.query('/ACES/Header') AS HeaderNode
      ,t.c.query('/ACES/Footer') AS FooterNode
from NETCHANGESource.dbo.tblFile s
CROSS APPLY s.col.nodes('/') AS t(c);   -- col is your XML column
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417107)**</kbd>

Comment: i am getting error like:Must declare the scalar variable "@x".

Comment: getting something like "Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.". kindly help.

Comment: @akhrot Please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com to recreate your case. With both table structures and sample data.

Comment: i am getting error in sqlfiddle.com. may i edit my question with the code which i am trying

Comment: @akhrot Check `HeaderNode VARCHAR (150),
FooterNode VARCHAR (150)` and in your original case `,HeaderNode XML
              ,FooterNode XML);` Change table structure to `XML` as before edit.